# Unable to catch SQLException . After upgrading same code. Java6 to 8

Tags: java, exception

We have AWT based application fetching values from DB. Doing upgrade Java6 to 8.
At one place in application, we are trying handle exceptions as below -

This part works well for Java6. However for Java8 the if condition is failing even though SQLState ="23000" and VendorCode=2292. I debug in eclipse and got the values at runtime.

One more thing I would like to add; In Java8 I am getting SQLIntegrityConstaintViolationException. However I hope that is not related or causing issue.

```
catch (SQLException ex)
        {

        if ((ex.getSQLState() == "23000") && (ex.getErrorCode() == 2292))
         throw new PersistentValidationException("DBCustomer: Delete restricted",ex);
        else
         throw new PersistentUIException("   DBCustomer:delete --- " +
            "SQL error occurred.",ex);
    }
```

Any suggestions

Comment: add a catch Exception, and check (during debug) the type of the Exception thrown

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Don't use "==" for string comparisons. Try to use "equals()" method for string comparisons.

Comment: This code is working in Java6.  However in Java8 I have to change to equals to make that work.

Strange!

But thanks guys for pinpointing.